# Selecting the first img from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html.

```
<div>
   <img class="foo">
   <a href="#" onClick="changeImage(this, param1, param2)">sth</a>
</div>
```

I want to change the class of image (remove `foo`, add `bar`) when user clicks on the link. However, I cannot write down the right selector for jquery.

I am also not sure if I really need to pass the `this` to the function.

```
function changeImage(link, param1, param2) {

    //Following line does not work
    $(link).parent('div img').removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also don't need to pass -this- into your onclick, we're not even effecting it in the function, and we can grab it regardless.

```
function changeImage(link, param1, param2) {

    //Following line does not work
    //$(link).parent('div img').removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");

    $(this).closest('div').find('img').removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
    return false; // stops the <a> link from doing anything else
}
```

On a side note: Try to never use any onclick/onmouseover/etc events on any DOM elements, each one individually creates a script block within legacy browsers (IE), and with hundreds/thousands of elements on  a page, it can deteriorate performance.

Use `.click()`, `.on()`, whatever version of jQuery you supports version instead.

Comment: Thanks, for the side tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

you  can do it like this

```
$(link).parent('div img:first').removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your markup will remain as you have shown in your question:

```
$(link).prev().removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
```

The `.prev()` method will select the immediately preceding sibling, which in your case is the `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   function changeImage(link, param1, param2) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('img:first').removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(link).prev('img').removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
```

OR

```
$(link).siblings('img').removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

***JS CODE***

```
function changeImage(link, param1, param2) {
    $(link).siblings().removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
}
```